# Save a UITextView attributed string to file in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, nsmutableattributedstring

I need to work with attributed strings (`NSMutableAttributedString`) in `SwiftUI` to make a simple rich-text editor, and as you might already know, attributed strings are not natively supported in SwiftUI. So I had to work with the old `UITextView` using a `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper.

Now, my app is a document-based app, and whenever I try to save the files, some strange problems happens:

**First Problem:** When I run the app and open a file, and start typing, the initial contents of the file are erased.

**Second Problem:** Whenever I write text and hit the back arrow to save file, it's never updated. All documents still have the same initial content.

[image]

The code for document processing is the default code that came when you create a new SwiftUI document-based app, but, I changed the encoding from plain text to `NSMutableAttributedString`. (I also created a document extension called .mxt instead of .txt)

***Document processing file `MyextDocument.swift`:***

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

extension UTType {
    static var MyextDocument = UTType(exportedAs: "com.example.Myext.mxt")
}

struct MyextDocument: FileDocument {
    var text: NSMutableAttributedString

    init(text: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()) {
        self.text = text
    }

    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.MyextDocument] }
    
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let string = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSMutableAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSMutableAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        text = string
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let data = (try? text.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, text.length), documentAttributes: [.documentType: NSMutableAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf]))!
        return .init(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}
```

***UIViewRepresentable wrapper file `iOSEditorTextView.swift`:***

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct iOSEditorTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    //@Binding var text: String
    @Binding var document: NSMutableAttributedString
    var isEditable: Bool = true
    var font: UIFont?    = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
    
    var onEditingChanged: () -> Void       = {}
    var onCommit        : () -> Void       = {}
    var onTextChange    : (String) -> Void = { _ in }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomTextView {
        let textView = CustomTextView(
            text: document,
            isEditable: isEditable,
            font: font
        )
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomTextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = document
        uiView.selectedRanges = context.coordinator.selectedRanges
    }
}

// MARK: - Preview

#if DEBUG

struct iOSEditorTextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            iOSEditorTextView(
                document: .constant(NSMutableAttributedString()),
                isEditable: true,
                font: .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
            )
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
            .previewDisplayName("Dark Mode")
            
            iOSEditorTextView(
                document: .constant(NSMutableAttributedString()),
                isEditable: false
            )
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
            .previewDisplayName("Light Mode")
        }
    }
}

#endif

// MARK: - Coordinator

extension iOSEditorTextView {
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: iOSEditorTextView
        var selectedRanges: [NSValue] = []
        
        init(_ parent: iOSEditorTextView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.document = textView.attributedText as! NSMutableAttributedString
            self.parent.onEditingChanged()
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.document = textView.attributedText as! NSMutableAttributedString
            //self.selectedRanges = textView.selectedRange
        }

        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.document = textView.attributedText as! NSMutableAttributedString
            self.parent.onCommit()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - CustomTextView

final class CustomTextView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    private var isEditable: Bool
    private var font: UIFont?
    
    weak var delegate: UITextViewDelegate?
    
    var text: NSMutableAttributedString {
        didSet {
            textView.attributedText = text
        }
    }
    
    var selectedRanges: [NSValue] = [] {
        didSet {
            guard selectedRanges.count > 0 else {
                return
            }
            
            //textView.selectedRanges = selectedRanges
        }
    }
        
    private lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        let textView                     = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        textView.delegate                = self.delegate
        textView.font                    = self.font
        textView.isEditable              = self.isEditable
        textView.textColor               = UIColor.label
        textView.textContainerInset      = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return textView
    }()

    // Create paragraph styles
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle() // create paragraph style

    var attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        .font: UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)!
    ]
    
    // MARK: - Init
    init(text: NSMutableAttributedString, isEditable: Bool, font: UIFont?) {
        self.font       = font
        self.isEditable = isEditable
        self.text       = text
        
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Life cycle
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        setupTextView()
        
        // Set tap gesture
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapTextView(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // create paragraph style
        self.paragraphStyle.headIndent = 108
        
        // create attributed string
        let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        
        // create attributes
        self.attributes = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
            .font: UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)!,
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        ]

        // Create the Attributed String
        let myAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
        
        // Write it to the Text View
        textView.attributedText = myAttrString
    }
    
    // Show cursor and set it to position on tapping + Detect line
    @objc func didTapTextView(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Show cursor and set it to position on tapping
        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            textView.isEditable = true
            textView.becomeFirstResponder()
                        
            let location = recognizer.location(in: textView)
            if let position = textView.closestPosition(to: location) {
                let uiTextRange = textView.textRange(from: position, to: position)
                
                if let start = uiTextRange?.start, let end = uiTextRange?.end {
                    let loc = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: position)
                    let length = textView.offset(from: start, to: end)
                    
                    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(loc, length)
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
        
    func setupTextView() {
        // Setup Text View delegate
        textView.delegate = self
        
        // Place the Text View on the view
        addSubview(textView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])

    }
}
```

***And to call the UIViewRepresentable wrapper, I wrote the following code in the `ContentView`:***

```
iOSEditorTextView(
    document: $document.text,
    isEditable: true,
    font: .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your code for your `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in `updateUIView`, does it show the correct text getting passed to your view before it turns blank?

Comment: I have attached the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/madawthcol0cnj4/Beta%20Project.zip?dl=0) Can you please give it a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in the code.

1. You have set the wrong delegate. So your delegate method not worked.
   Give self delegate, not-self. like

```
func setupTextView() {
    // Setup Text View delegate
    textView.delegate = delegate
```

2. Use `NSMutableAttributedString` in the delegate.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.parent.document = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
    self.parent.onEditingChanged()
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.parent.document = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.parent.document = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
    self.parent.onCommit()
}
```

3. Remove static text from `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` this line overrides the existing text.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        setupTextView()
        
        // Set tap gesture
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapTextView(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // create paragraph style
        self.paragraphStyle.headIndent = 108
        
        // create attributes
        self.attributes = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
            .font: UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)!,
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        ]
    }
```

Note: Remove other code from draw rect and use init or `func awakeFromNib()`

Comment: Great, Thanks Raga! Since your answer solves the problem, I've chosen it as the correct Answer.
However, if I move the code from `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` to `init(text: NSMutableAttributedString, isEditable: Bool, font: UIFont?)`, the files are not saved correctly (same problem again).

Answer (score 2):

All of Raja's issues are correct.  The other thing that I would do differently is not pass a `struct` value to your `Coordinator` as the delegate, as you can't guarantee that the same instance of it will be available later on.  Much better to pass a binding to your mutable string instead.  So:

```
extension iOSEditorTextView {
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var documentBinding : Binding<NSMutableAttributedString>
        var selectedRanges: [NSValue] = []
        
        init(_ documentBinding: Binding<NSMutableAttributedString>) {
            self.documentBinding = documentBinding
        }
        
        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            documentBinding.wrappedValue = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            documentBinding.wrappedValue = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
            //self.selectedRanges = textView.selectedRange
        }

        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            documentBinding.wrappedValue = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($document)
    }
```